# IAR Embedded workbench 6 (MSP430 V5.6) Overriding program start

Tags: c99, msp430, iar

I am using IAR embedded workbench for MSP430 v5.60.7, which is IAR embedded workbench version 6.6. I am using C99.

I am trying to override __program_start() with my own symbol, a function called __unit_test_main(). I have gone to the linker config tab and checked the box "override default program entry", selected the "entry symbol" option and typed in __unit_test_main. This compiles and links however it does not run in the simulator. I get the message "User error: Illegal opcode found on address 0x0". When I try to run this on the target it just doesn't work - the controller goes into low power mode.

The PC and SP are both initialized to 0x00 at startup.

So what else do I need to do/define to get the PC and SP initialized properly?

My unit test main function is trivial right now, here's the whole file its in:

```
    #include <cstdio>
    void __unit_test_main(void);
    void __unit_test_main(void)
    {
        printf("Hello World");
        for(;;)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can call library functions in that function. If I have understood correctly, you are taking over the program when initialization work is not yet done; `.bss` section is not zeroed and `.data` section is not initialized. This likely means that any global variables required by library funcions (I imagine `printf` has some) have garbage values. Note: This is just a guess, I haven't worked with MSP, or entry overriding.

Comment: I can't even run to __unit_test_main though - not sure why that would have anything to do with the CLIB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__program_start:` is defined in cstartup.s43. This file can be copied into your project directory and included in your project which overrides the library version.

Immediately after `__program_start:` label the stack pointer is initialized, `__low_level_init()` is called, and then `?cstart_call_main` is called.

Around the `?cstart_call_main:` label (line 339) is the following:

```
    XRSEGCSTART
    PUBLIC  ?cstart_call_main

    EXTERN  main
    EXTERN  exit

?cstart_call_main:
    XXCALL  main
    XXCALL  exit
```

There you can add the symbol of the function you want to replace main with.

You can do it conditionally with some `#ifdef` preprocessor logic.

So I have

```
    XRSEGCSTART
    PUBLIC  ?cstart_call_main
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
    EXTERN  test_runner_main
#else
    EXTERN  main
#endif
    EXTERN  exit

?cstart_call_main:
#ifdef  UNIT_TEST
    XXCALL  test_runner_main
#else
    XXCALL  main
#endif
    XXCALL  exit

    PUBLIC  ?cstart_end
```

I had to define my UNIT_TEST symbol in the assembler and the compiler options.

Another option would have been implementing the function `__low_level_init()` somewhere in my project and conditionally making a call to test_runner instead of calling `main()`